# java.net.ConnectException: Conection refused, but telnet works

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

I have a problem with java sockets.

I am able to start the server and keep it waiting for incoming connections.

When I am trying to connect with my client I get a Connection refused error.

When I connect to my server with telnet, it works. There's also no problem with connecting on localhost.

I registered the port in my router's settings and turned the firewalls of both computers off.

I use Windows 7 Professional 64bit on both machines.

Here's the code of my connection class:
(In my program the client and server are reversed because my server application connects to all clients, so the client creates the server. I hope that doesn't cause confusion :D )

```js
 private void connectClient(int port)
 {
  try
  {
   server = new ServerSocket(port);
   System.out.println("Starting connection...");
   client = server.accept();
   br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
   pw = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
   System.out.println("Server connected!");
   while(!"disconnect".equalsIgnoreCase(data))
   {
    Thread.sleep(100);
   }
  }
  catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
  {
   try
   {
    if(client != null)
    {
     client.close();
    }
    if(server != null)
    {
     server.close();
    }
   }
   catch (IOException e1)
   {
    e1.printStackTrace();
   }
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
 
 private void connectServer(String IP, int port)
 {
  try
  {
   client = new Socket(IP,port);
   br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
   pw = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
   while(!"disconnect".equalsIgnoreCase(data))
   {
    Thread.sleep(100);
   }
  }
  catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
   try
   {
    if(client != null)
    {
     client.close();
    }
   }
   catch (IOException e1)
   {
    e1.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Nice multicatch; why aren't you using [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)?